# listrak push notification implementation in Xamarin or using web api calls in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

As Listrak does not support Xamarin, it only have Android studio package 
https://github.com/listrak/Listrak-Android-SDK/tree/main/com/listrak/ListrakSDK.Android/1.0.0
But it does not have supporting package for Xamarin Andriod application. Is there any option to work Listrak push notification with Xamarin application by using web api or any class library.

Thanks & regards,
Sandy

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/

Comment: Thanks Jason, Listrak only provided Android base library can use same for Xamarin IOS application

Comment: no, you cannot use an Android library in an iOS app